# Join two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I need something like:

```
select * 
from table1 
where {if PKID = MasterPKID - (that PKID should not be present as refNo in table2)}.
```

ie- 652 should not be present in Table2

I am totally clueless.

Can we achieve it in one query?

Comment: `if PKID = MasterPKID - (that PKID should not be present as refNo in table2)` . What do you mean by that. Please give appropriate example with some more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Not exists`

```
select * 
from table1 a
where PKID = MasterPKID
and not exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.PKID = b.refno)
```

Comment: Can these be achieved with JOIN as well?

Comment: That is a join -- technically, it's an anti-join. EXISTS on its own is a semi-join.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these!!

If MaterPKID can contain NULL Values then go for `not exists`

```
select * 
from table1 a
where PKID = MasterPKID
and not exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.PKID = b.refno)
```

else go with `not in`

```
select * 
from table1 a
where PKID = MasterPKID
and PKID not in (select REFNO from table2)
```

Comment: I would think about the impact of nulls the other way round -- if you specifically want a NULL in the subquery to cause the predicate to evaluate as false (pretty rare condition) then use NOT IN, but otherwise use NOT EXISTS for everything.